# MLM / HLM Equal sample sizes needed between groups?

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, sample-size, multilevel-analysis, group-differences

I am working on analyzing a dataset from a diary study (6–14 repeated measures per participant). The sample I have consists of 2 groups (1 with expertise, 1 without) that are thought to differ on many of our key variables. I have more participants in the experise group (200) vs the non-expertise group (150).

I had been advised that it is best to have equal sample sizes between these groups, but I am not sure if this advice applies to my planned analyses. I will be doing t-tests between groups for the aggregated daily variables, as well as MLM / HLM with person-centered variables for the within-person differences.

If I were to drop the last 50 participants from the experise group, I would have equal groups. But obviously, I don't want to drop participants unless it is actually necessary.

Any advice &/or references would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not advise dropping the "extra" 50 participants. This will lead to a reduction in statistical power. While, in a perfect world, it is better to have equal sized groups (more statistical power), mixed effects models work well with unbalanced data, so I would advise to proceed with your whole dataset.

My other advice with this study is to be careful about the residual covariance structure. You are very likely to have autocorrelation within participants and this needs to be handled carefully. AR(1) is often used, but it is also problematic for several reasons. Some software for fitting mixed models offer many different covariance structures (with "unstructured" being the most flexible, but this also comes with problems when there are many time points. Luckily there are good alternatives such as Toeplitz and ante-dependence).